# What is this syntax in this code about lambda of Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, inline-functions

I'm studying about Kotlin's inline function just after
Kotiln's lambda,,,

below code is about Kotlin's inline function example

I know that "return" can't be in lambda in Kotlin

But What is a "return"(at line 4)?
Why is there "return" in lambda?????
How??

(below code is working well,,,)

```
fun main() {
    shortFunc(3){
        println("First call: $it")
        return
    }
}

inline fun shortFunc(a: Int, out: (Int)->Unit){
    println("Before calling out()")
    out(a)
    println("After calling out()")
}
```

Comment: When a higher order function is marked as `inline`, its function-parameters will also be inlined if it's possible. If you pass a lambda function to such a function, then you will be able to return from the outer function (in this case `main`) inside the lambda, becaus it is inlined.

Answer (score 1):

In general `return` is not allowed in a lambda, but `shortFunc` is marked as `inline`. That allows for *non-local returns*, and in this specific case that `return` will make the code return from the enclosing function – which is `main`, so your program terminates.

You can read more about non-local returns [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns) and [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels)